# Set page title in WordPress with PHP

Tags: page-template, title, wp-title

I know this question has been asked thousands of times before, but I have attempted a lots of these solutions without any success.

Attempted solutions, among others (added to the template page)

```
add_filter('the_title','callback_to_set_the_title');

add_filter('wp_title', 'callback_to_set_the_title');

global $title;
$title = 'My Custom Title';

add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'callback_to_set_the_title' );

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'callback_to_set_the_title' );
```

The scenario is that I have a custom template for a job listing page. This page has url rewriting in place that rewrites `domain.com/about/careers/search/job?slug=whatever` to `domain.com/about/careers/search/job/whatever` - the slug is used to retrieve an entry from Redis that contains all the info for the job listing including the title I'd like to use.

Here's how I am rewriting the URL (from functions.php):

```
function job_listing_url_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%slug%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^about/careers/search/job/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=6633&slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
add_action('init', 'job_listing_url_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

Comment: Where is the `callback_to_set_the_title` function? Can you include it in your question? If the title is coming from a Redis instance then how are you displaying the title? Also note that flushing rewrite rules on every page load is bad practice and can cause issues

Comment: Because I am getting what I want for the title from Redis, I am calling this within the template.  The call back function looks like this:


function callback_to_set_the_title() {
    return $job['title'];
}


Where $job is the object retrieved from Redis

Comment: Yes but how are you displaying the title? `the_title()`? `echo $title;`?

Comment: Im referring to the Browser Tab title for SEO, not the page title.